# session_write_close(): Session callback expects true/false return value

Tags: php, slim

I'm new to Slim Framework. I'm supposed to work with the previous version of Slim as required by my org. So, I got the existing Slim library and When I run with index.php I get the following error.

```
Message: session_write_close(): Session callback expects true/false return value
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\slim\Slim\Slim.php
Line: 810
```

the following is my index.php

```
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
$app = new Slim();
$app->get('/hello/:name', function ($name) {
echo "Hello, $name";
});
$app->run();
```

The error traces back to Slim.php

```
805:   public function stop() {
806:   $flash = $this->view->getData('flash');
807:        if ( $flash ) {
808:          $flash->save();
809:        }
810:        session_write_close();
811:        $this->response->send();
812:        throw new Slim_Exception_Stop();
813:    }
```

P.s I m completely new to Slim.

Comment: https://github.com/pydio/pydio-core/issues/1139

Comment: sorry anish.. this doesn't fix it up

Comment: Which php version did you use?

Comment: @AnishChandran PHP 7.0

Comment: session_write_close(true);

Comment: not the parameter value. the return value. I m not sure where this function is defined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138542/discussion-between-kishram-and-anish-chandran).